# Menu Inflater doesn't render items outside menu xml

Tags: java, android, xml, menu, toolbar

I am trying to create menu according to https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-App-Toolbar

Menu items are shown perfectly only in menu_main.xml. I cant see items in toolbar_main.xml or activity_main.xml... According to other solutions posted on stack, I didn't solve my problem. Everything is done according to these docs at codepath and should work.

[image: menu_main.xml]
[image: activity_main.xml]
[image: MainActivity.java]

What should be done to see menu in main activity, or this is normal behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that's normal behavior. Strange not to see render in root coming from web :D